# Largest palindrome product in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve problem 4 from project euler (Q: find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers). I get 580085 as answer but it is not the correct. What I'm doing wrong? not looking for a different implementation just wanted to know whats wrong with my implementation.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int reverse_num(int num) 
{
    int ret = 0, value = 1, temp = 0;
    temp = num;
    while(temp>0)
    {       
        temp = temp/10;
        value = value * 10;
    }
    value = value/10;

    while(num>0)
    {
        temp = num % 10;
        temp = temp * value;
        ret = ret + temp;
        num = num/10;
        value = value/10;
    }

    return ret;
}

int check_palindrome(int num)
{
    if(num==reverse_num(num))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num = 0, i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;

    for(i=100; i<1000; i++)
    {
        for(j=100; j<1000; j++)
        {
            temp = i * j;
            if(check_palindrome(temp))
            {
                printf("found %d palindrome, its product of %d and %d\n", temp, i, j);
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking it is largest?

Comment: 580085 is the last number your program outputs, but not the biggest.

Comment: as pointed out by @EugeneSh. I have updated program to check for largest palindrome

Comment: after the changes made for checking largest palindrome i was able to get the correct answer, thanks @EugeneSh.

Comment: Not for nothing, but why are you counting up, rather than down?

Comment: Your amended question gives the right answer now as the last line of output - I just compiled and ran it.

Comment: @AustinHastings I'm still learning, my aim was to solve the problem and not to write optimized code

Comment: @chux let me revert it back to original and post my own answer to accept it

Comment: @AustinHastings It actually doesn't save much to count downwards. You have to introduce extra checks in each loop to make them terminate early and the program as written takes 0.08 seconds on my laptop at `-Onone`.

Comment: @chux its not allowing me to accept the answer now and says I need to wait for two days, I will accept it after two days. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as questioned by Eugene Sh. I added a check for the largest palindrome and now it works, below is the code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse_num(int num) 
{
    int ret = 0, value = 1, temp = 0;
    temp = num;
    while(temp>0)
    {       
        temp = temp/10;
        value = value * 10;
    }
    value = value/10;

    while(num>0)
    {
        temp = num % 10;
        temp = temp * value;
        ret = ret + temp;
        num = num/10;
        value = value/10;
    }

    return ret;
}

int check_palindrome(int num)
{
    if(num==reverse_num(num))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num = 0, i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0, largest = 0;

    for(i=100; i<1000; i++)
    {
        for(j=100; j<1000; j++)
        {
            temp = i * j;
            if(check_palindrome(temp))
            {
                if(temp>largest)
                {
                    largest = temp;
                    printf("found largest %d palindrome, its product of %d and %d\n", largest, i, j);
                }
                //printf("found %d palindrome, its product of %d and %d\n", temp, i, j);
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `reverse_num(int num)`, with larger `num` can needlessly overflow and generate the wrong answer even when the palindrome is representable in `int` unlike [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43501686/2410359).  Not a issue, though, with 32-bit `int`  when `0 <= num < 1000000`.

Answer (score 1):

Your reverse algorithm works even though you could do it more efficiently.

```
int reverse_num(int num)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
       int digit = num % 10;
       result = result * 10 + digit;
       num /= 10;
    }
    return result;
```

I think you'll get more than one print line. You might also find that the right answer is not necessarily the last answer printed, especially as you work out every product twice.

**Edit**

The question was amended after I wrote this answer. The code in the question now works.